# img src is not working for static image in mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, imgsource

In view I want to show image which is store in view folder named Errorpage.png. Now, I want to show that image in Error.cshtml view file.

Here is my code

```
<img src="~/Views/Errorpage.png" alt="error">
```

Now , this code is not working and showing error alt in the place of image. While the path is perfectly right, but surprised that why it is not working.

While I tried by fetch the online image and that is work.

Here is the code

```
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/anton-ploom.jpg" 
    alt="A danseur in brisé (a leap with the legs together) on a blue background">
```

Now, I am confused that this second code is working properly while the first code is not working.

The syntax is same both of the code.

Thank You.

Comment: Use `@Url.Content()` i.e. `<img src="@Url.Content("~/Views/Errorpage.png")`" alt="error">`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this way:

> can you please put your image in image folder outside Views folder
>   that can work

or

```
  <img alt="error" src="@Url.Content("/Views/Errorpage.png")" />
```

if that doesn't work you could try with this way:

```
<img alt="error" src="/Views/Errorpage.png" />
```

or there is another solution if all are fails :

```
<img alt="error" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Views/Errorpage.png") %>" />
```

Comment: is there any other way to display the image

Comment: your code is on any server ? can you provide me a link?

Comment: can you please put your image in image folder outside Views folder that can work

Comment: yup now it is working after putting image in the folder

Answer (score 0):

in visual studio, the image works from ~/contents/*.jpeg directory.
if you will put it in any other directory it will not work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
 <img  src="@Url.Content("~/Views/Errorpage.png")"  alt="error"/>
```